# What programming languages are used in Android OS development?

Tags: operating-system, development

I know we can develop Android apps in Java and also that the base of Android is Linux. However, I don't know what programming languages are used in the Android Open Source Project.

I try to find out the answer to this question many times but was still unable to find out an answer.

Any idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As mentioned on its [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_%28operating_system%29), Android's core is developed in C and C++, and Java is used for the UI. You can see this for yourself if you browse the Android source code. For example, [Google Git](https://android.googlesource.com/) provides the source for browsing without the need to download gigabytes of data.

Answer (score 3):

As you told in question itself, Android is **Linux** based.

So obviously the core is developed using **C**.

On top of this, **Java** is used for UI (ie: **Android**).